# SDK minimum or best pages install

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

**UPDATE:** Todays time android automatic suggest and check marked the required packages.

[image]

I am so much confuse about installing Android SDK packages. What packages should I install from this long list. I am beginner student and it not make any sense to me what things does what.

I need a minimalistic setup for very basic or beginner level app development.

<del>what the best installation for eclipse (minimum packages).</del>

Give me best idea for this install packages.

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious that the items you need are going to depend on what you're doing. You'd need to provide more information on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to develop for API 15 and above, then just download API 15-23 to get the minimum download as well as maximum tools. API 15 is what I use as it takes up 90+% of the Android market, and is a good choice.

I would recommend you download all the Extras, especially the HAXM if you are planning to use the Android emulator to develop instead of testing your app on a real device.

For the Tools/Build-Tools/Platform-Tools, I suggest only downloading the latest version, and if you are planning to save space, delete it and download the next latest version which can be seen in the Rev. column. As a beginner, I recommend you don't try out the Tools(Preview Channel) as they can still contain glitches or are unstable as they are still in alpha.